# Installing mvtnorm package on new R 3.3.0

Tags: r, gcc, install.packages

I'm using a linux server to run my R codes. Recently, the R software on the server has been updated to the newest 3.3.0 version. Since then, I've got a lot of problems installing different packages. In specific, I'm trying to simply install "mvtnorm" package by running:

```
install.packages("mvtnorm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", dependencies=T)
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
```

The error is much longer. I'm copying below in case if you want to see more details.

I really appreciate your help as I'm completely clueless what to do.

Thanks,

---

Full Error:

```
install.packages("mvtnorm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", dependencies=T)
Installing package into ‘/home/akhavans/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 337237 bytes (329 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 329 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
mvt.f:5.72:

     &                   MAXPTS, ABSEPS, RELEPS, ERROR, VALUE, INFORM )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:86.33:

      SUBROUTINE MVSUBR( N, W, NF, F )
                                 1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'nf' at (1)
mvt.f:200.72:

      SUBROUTINE MVVLSB( N,W,R,DL,INFI, A,B,COV, Y, DI,EI, ND, VALUE )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:368.72:

                  IF ( INFI(I) .NE. 0 ) Y(I) =        MVTDNS( 0, AMIN )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:369.72:

                  IF ( INFI(I) .NE. 1 ) Y(I) = Y(I) - MVTDNS( 0, BMIN )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:874.72:

      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION MVBVT( NU, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, CORREL )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:1045.72:

         bvt = atan2(-snu*(hkn*qhrk+hpk*hkrn),hkn*hkrn-nu*hpk*qhrk)/tpi
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:1199.72:

> install.packages("mvtnorm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", dependencies=T)
Installing package into ‘/home/akhavans/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 337237 bytes (329 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 329 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
mvt.f:5.72:

     &                   MAXPTS, ABSEPS, RELEPS, ERROR, VALUE, INFORM )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:86.33:

      SUBROUTINE MVSUBR( N, W, NF, F )
                                 1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'nf' at (1)
mvt.f:200.72:

      SUBROUTINE MVVLSB( N,W,R,DL,INFI, A,B,COV, Y, DI,EI, ND, VALUE )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:368.72:

                  IF ( INFI(I) .NE. 0 ) Y(I) =        MVTDNS( 0, AMIN )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:369.72:

                  IF ( INFI(I) .NE. 1 ) Y(I) = Y(I) - MVTDNS( 0, BMIN )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:874.72:

      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION MVBVT( NU, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, CORREL )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:1045.72:

         bvt = atan2(-snu*(hkn*qhrk+hpk*hkrn),hkn*hkrn-nu*hpk*qhrk)/tpi
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:1199.72:

         FINEST(K) = FINEST(K) + ( FINVAL(K) - FINEST(K) )/( 1+VARPRD )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
mvt.f:1391.72:

            VALUES(J) = VALUES(J) + ( FS(J) - VALUES(J) )/( 2*K-1 )
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c mvtnorm-init.c -o mvtnorm-init.o
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c tvpack.f -o tvpack.o
tvpack.f:65.52:

      DOUBLE PRECISION ONE, ZRO, EPS, ZROS(3), HS(3), TVT, TVTL
                                                    1
Warning: Unused variable 'hs' declared at (1)
tvpack.f:65.45:

      DOUBLE PRECISION ONE, ZRO, EPS, ZROS(3), HS(3), TVT, TVTL
                                             1
Warning: Unused variable 'zros' declared at (1)
tvpack.f: In function ‘adonet’:
tvpack.f:201: warning: ‘fin’ may be used uninitialized in this function
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -ldl -lpthread -lc -lrt -lcurl -lidn -lssh2 -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lldap -lz -lrt -o mvtnorm.so C_FORTRAN_interface.o miwa.o mvt.o mvtnorm-init.o tvpack.o -ldl -lpthread -lrt /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/zlib-1.2.8/target/usr/lib64/libz.a /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/bzip2-1.0.6/target/usr/lib64/libbz2.a /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/xz-5.2.2/target/usr/lib64/liblzma.a /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/pcre-8.38/target/usr/lib64/libpcre.a /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/curl-7.48.0/target/usr/lib64/libcurl.a -lcurl -lidn -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lldap -lz -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
gcc: /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/zlib-1.2.8/target/usr/lib64/libz.a: No such file or directory
gcc: /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/bzip2-1.0.6/target/usr/lib64/libbz2.a: No such file or directory
gcc: /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/xz-5.2.2/target/usr/lib64/liblzma.a: No such file or directory
gcc: /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/pcre-8.38/target/usr/lib64/libpcre.a: No such file or directory
gcc: /builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/curl-7.48.0/target/usr/lib64/libcurl.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [mvtnorm.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/home/akhavans/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/mvtnorm’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/lv_scratch/tmp/RtmpbuSB0J/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("mvtnorm", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org",  :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Did you update RTools?

Comment: He uses Linux, so no RTools necessary.

Comment: It look like your system is missing some libraries, so use `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` in your console and add then to your PATH.